# Error referencing a PHP script on a local server

Tags: java, android, mysql, apache2

Following this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/
But I'm modifying and adopting it for personal use.

First lets start with the error:

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value create_product.php of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
VM exiting with result code 0, cleanup skipped.
```

^the exit is merely because I put a simple if (jsonobject==null){System.exit(0);}

Ruling things out: 
When I use "http://api.androidhive.info/android_connect/create_product.php" as my testURL instead of my own "ttp://192.168.1.8/HypeServer/android_connect/create_product.php" the json parses properly and replies not enough parameters - which is the proper output.

In this scenario the only variable that appears to be changing is the server address - as that's literally the only line I have to change to go between a functioning module and a non-operational one. So I figure the problem is with my server configuration setup.

My server is accessible from my laptop and another computer on the network. I copied the link exactly into my code. Running the php scripts also works using the gui even just not java code within android studio. I'm using my phone which is on the same wifi network as me and seems to be grabbing at least some form of data from my server it just doesn't seem to be running the script.

Versions:
LAMP - Ubuntu(14.04) - Apache(2.4.7) - MySQL(5.5.37) - PHP(5.5.9)

I taught myself pretty much all of this so its quite possible I'm missing some huge obvious concept but I am just stumped. On another note if I'm doing something else that is very bad I'd love to know.

Here's all relevant code:

```
public class ServerConnectActivity extends ActionBarActivity{


// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

// url to get all products list
private static String url_create_user = "http://192.168.1.8/HypeServer/android_connect/create_product.php";
        //"http://192.168.1.8/HypeServer/android_connect/create_account.php";


// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

//list of data to be added
protected List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
}

public void setData() {
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "Ev0xFrost"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "lamda"));
}
public void setHttp(String s) {
    s = url_create_user;
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    return true;
}


public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
 return true;

}
/**  
 * Background Async Task to Create new product
 */
protected class CreateNewGeneric extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

/**
 * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
 */
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    setData();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ServerConnectActivity.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Logging in..");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    pDialog.show();
}

/**
 * Creating product
 */
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

    // getting JSON Object
    // Note that create product url accepts POST method
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_user,
            "POST", params);

    // check log cat fro response
    if (json == null) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

    // check for success tag
    try {
        int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

        if (success == 1) {
            // successfully created product
            Intent i = new Intent(ServerConnectActivity.this, TimelineActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

            // closing this screen
            finish();
        } else {
            // failed to create product
            //TODO: tell users there was a problem connecting with the servers?
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
 * *
 */
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // dismiss the dialog once done
    pDialog.dismiss();
}

}

}
```

--

```
public class MainActivity extends ServerConnectActivity {

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.Hype.Hype.MESSAGE";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //disables the action bar
    supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


    Button btnCreateUser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    // button click event
    btnCreateUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating new product in background thread
            new CreateNewGeneric().execute();
        }
    });

}


public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}


public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}

}
```

-- his php script is linked --  my version is an exact copy - actually its written to work with a create_user.php script but since both scripts produced the same error I went ahead and decided to rule out bad php coding.

Comment: MakeHttpRequest is returning null. So you have to dig into thst method. Add log statements to see how far execution goes and determine the place where null is returned. Care for printStackTrace in catch blocks. And for now post the logcat here as there will be an errormessage already.

Comment: Try your url in a browser on your phone. What does it report? Can it connect?

Comment: I can connect to the server on my phone and successfully run php scripts.
Trying to run that particular script from my phone - create_account.php{"success":0,"messsage":"Required field(s) is missing"}

Comment: Very very confusing answer. Where are you talking about? Be clear. There is one or there are more browsers on your phone. And you have your app on your phone. In above answer you do not use the word 'browser' and you are also not using 'my app'. So I don't know what you ment. Please rephrase.

Comment: Following your advice - thanks a bunch in advance btw - seems I've found where it goes wrong.
The string build by the string buffer:
create_product.php {"success":0,"message":"Required field(s) is missing"}
trimming... json = json.substring(json.indexOf('{'));
and I now get the correct response
toying around I found that since I had create_account.php at the top of my php file (before the <php? tag) it was always being outputted... and generally messing everything up. 
Removed the bad line. Deleted the line that was trimming and well..
its all fixed. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: haha sorry yeah that was an incomplete thought. I was about to just update you but then I found the problem.